# Timing and VCL synchronize (in/from thread)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timing, synchronize

I would like to refresh a Treenode.text (with the elapsed time) and use a timer from the same thread. As i read its not recommend to use TTimer* in a thread, but then, what to use instead? Thank You.

*I want to use some timing instead of sleep(). Not just because thats cheesy(?), but i have to, because otherwise i can refresh treenodetext only in every sec.) >>

```
unit master_slave

...

Tsrch_slave_thread = class(TThread)   
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  master: TMaster;         
end;

TMaster = class(TObject)
private
  ...
  FMasterNode: TTreeview; 
  Fsw: TStopWatch;
  Fslave_search_thread : Tsrch_slave_thread;
  ...
end;

...

implementation

...

procedure Tsrch_slave_thread.Execute;
var
  searchactive: integer;
begin
  while not terminated do begin
    searchactive := master.CMD_LISTCNT 
    if searchactive = 1 then //(master.CMD_LISTCNT's return value = 1, if master finished search on the bus)
      exit;
    sleep(1000); //dont want to flood the master with UDP packets... (master.CMD_LISTCNT sends UDP packets)
    synchronize(procedure begin
      with FmasterNode do  
        text := text + floattostr(Fsw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
    end);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Sleep(1000)`, use a waitable event.

For example [`TSimpleEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TSimpleEvent).

```
FMySimpleEvent.WaitFor(1000);
```

If you want to exit the thread early, override the `TThread.DoTerminate` method and call:

```
FMySimpleEvent.SetEvent;
```

Something like this:

```
procedure Tsrch_slave_thread.Execute;
var
  searchactive: integer;
begin
  while not terminated do begin
    searchactive := master.CMD_LISTCNT 
    if searchactive = 1 then (master.CMD_LISTCNT's return value = 1, if search finished)
      exit;
    if (FMySimpleEvent.WaitFor(1000) = wrTimeOut) then
      synchronize(procedure begin
        with FmasterNode do  
          text := text + floattostr(Fsw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
      end);
  end;
end;

procedure Tsrch_slave_thread.DoTerminate;
begin
  Inherited;
  FMySimpleEvent.SetEvent;
end;
```

Comment: +1.  This is the right way to handle waiting on a specific action to finish.  `Sleep` or timers should only be used to handle something based on *a specific length of time*; when waiting on a discrete event, use a waitable signal.

Comment: @Mason this code is waiting a specific length of time

Comment: @LU RD, Thank you. (Why i cannot call free on TStopWatch?)

Comment: [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) is a record with methods, aka an advanced record. It is not allocated on the heap and does not need to be freed.

Comment: uh, because i saw one of your example freeing a TStopWatch instance, but now i see that was a class based on a delphi.about article.

Comment: Yes, before `TStopWatch` was incorporated into Delphi RTL, it was published as a class, see [`How to Accurately Measure Elapsed Time Using High-Resolution Performance Counter`](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-high-performance-timer-tstopwatch.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer in a thread, just not a `TTimer`. You have to make your own based on `SetTimer`. And you also need to make your own window to process the messages because you cannot use `AllocateHWnd` in a thread. Now, if you know that you won't show any modal dialogs or run any modal sizing loops or modal menu loops, then you could use a windowless timer.

But all this forces you to implement a message loop in your thread. Which adds another layer of complexity. Implementing a timer in a background thread is one of the few scenarios where a blocking approach is reasonable. I suggest you adopt this approach.

If your interval is short enough then you may use `Sleep`. The downside is that you need to wait for the call to `Sleep` to return before the thread can be terminated. So this may be a problem for longer intervals.

If you want to be able to terminate instantly you can instead of using `Sleep`, wait on an event with a timeout, using `WaitForSingleObject`, or one of the event classes defined in the `SyncObjs` unit. If the timeout elapses, your timer has elapsed. If the event is signaled, then your thread is expected to terminate.

Comment: Wanted to use a timer because that way i can refresh treenode less than a second, but thats really worthless to do. Will stay with FMySimpleEvent.WaitFor or sleep(). Thank you.

Comment: Sleep, timers and events have the same resolution. All can have frequency much greater than 1Hz.

Comment: Yes, but i have to leave it at 1sec, because i dont want to send udp packets more frequent. The original idea was: Send udp packets only in every 1sec, but refresh the treenode.text in lets say every 10ms.